# Stay in the saved form when it is called by ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms

It is a menu order form (bscreated.php). When clicked on the pulldown and select a date the text of the menu changed via ajax (menu text changed from mysql)
[Order form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1Bre.gif)

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "bscreatedsp.php",
      data: { date: selectedValue, appnr: selectedappId}
}).done(function( msg ) {
      $("#responsecontainer").html(msg);
});
```

When I click on save in the form, I want to stay on the same page. When I use _self I get only the form page bscreatedsp.php. When I used bscreated.php, I get the empty form.

So I have two questions, Is this the right way to do this or is the a better way? If yes, how can I stay in the same form/page?

Comment: Put the code you want to run when you ajax in a seperate file. Treat you ajax calls like a subroutime library for want of a better description. This ither file shoudl just perform a function, no HTML etc needed at all

Comment: My guess is that you have a form and submit button, so you are not preventing the default behaviour of the form

Capture the submit event and call preventDefault() on it.

Comment: RiggsFolly, you are right. I put the ajax response in a array. Thanks for the hint.